# Why won't this Mathematica code maximize?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, maximize, mathematica-8

```
f[n_] := ((A*n^a)^(1/s) + 
        c*(B*(a*c*(B/A)^(1/s)*n^(1 - (a/s)))^(-(a*s)/(a - s)))^(1/s))^s +
        b*log (1 - n - ((a*c*(B/A)^(1/s)*n^(1 - (a/s)))^(-(a*s)/(a - s))))
        d/dn (f (n))
        d/dn (f[n])
        D[f[n], n]
        solve (D[f[n], n] = 0)
        0
        Solve[D[f[n], n] = 0, n]
        Solve[0, n]
        Maximize[f[n], n]
        Maximize[b log (1 - n - (a (B/A)^(1/s) c n^(1 - a/s))^(-((a s)/(a - s)))) + ((A n^a)^(1/s) 
                     + c (B (a (B/A)^(1/s) c n^(1 - a/s))^(-((a s)/(a - s))))^(1/s))^s, n]
```

I am not getting anything returning for any of these functions. Any idea why?

Attaching a photo of the mathematica script:

[image]

Comment: did you not read the answer to your other question? or do you have a variable named `log`?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you're using solve with a lowercase, which is just an undefined variable.  To use the function `Solve` you need to write it with a capital letter.  In the same way, you have to write `Log` with a capital letter, not a lower-case letter, since it's a built in function.

Second, your open parenthesis is not a bracket.  Functions in Mathematica require brackets, like `Solve[ ... ]`, not `Solve(  )`.

Third, you're using `=` instead of `==`.  The single equals `=` is used to store variables, the double equals `==` is used to represent equality.

See if you can get it to work after remedying these errors.